# Web scraping: how to iterate over all the pages from a url and store the result in a table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am not able to resolve this loop. I want to iterate over all pages from the URL and put all the names in a table. There are 102 pages. Thank you in advance.

```
    [from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import re
    import requests

    url = "https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/hindu/"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    next_page = soup.find('a', {'class': 'next'}).get('href')
    l=(f'{next_page}')
    new_url=url+l
    link=soup.find('span', {'class' : \['a name-details girl-names', 'a name-details boy-names'\] })
    print("href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))

    while True:
      r = requests.get(new_url)
      soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
      next_page = soup.find('a', {'class': 'next'}).get('href')
      link=soup.find('span', {'class' : \['a name-details girl-names', 'a name-details boy-names'\] })

      print("href='>%s'>%s</a>" % (link.get("href"), link.text))
      l=(f'{next_page}')
      new_url=url+l




     if BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")is True:
           break][1]    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgM4I.png
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the issue is? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re
from prettytable import PrettyTable


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        p = PrettyTable()
        p.field_names = ['Name', 'Url']
        for item in range(1, 3):
            r = req.get(url.format(item))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

            for item in soup.findAll("span", class_=re.compile("a name")):
                p.add_row([item.a.text, f'{url[:25]}{item.a.get("href")}'])
        print(p)


main("https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/hindu/page-{}.html")
```

Output:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|      Name     |                                Url                                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
|     Aabha     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aabha-13597.html     |
|    Aabheer    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aabheer-2.html      |
|     Aachal    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aachal-20815.html     |
|    Aadarsh    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadarsh-3.html      |
|   Aadarshini  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadarshini-20997.html   |
|     Aadav     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadav-21329.html     |
|    Aadavan    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadavan-19505.html    |
|     Aadesh    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadesh-4.html       |
|     Aadhan    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhan-5.html       |
|   Aadharsha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadharsha-20812.html   |
|     Aadhik    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhik-19726.html     |
|   Aadhikesav  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhikesav-21003.html   |
|   Aadhinath   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhinath-21392.html   |
|    Aadhira    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhira-6.html      |
|    Aadhira    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhira-20603.html    |
|    Aadhith    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhith-21626.html    |
|    Aadhriti   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhriti-20601.html    |
|    Aadhunik   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhunik-21198.html    |
|   Aadhvitha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhvitha-20571.html   |
|     Aadhya    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadhya-21327.html     |
|      Aadi     |       https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadi-7.html        |
|    Aadidev    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadidev-8.html      |
|  Aadilakshmi  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadilakshmi-20995.html  |
|   Aadimoolan  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadimoolan-20920.html   |
|    Aadinadh   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadinadh-20614.html    |
|    Aadinath   |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadinath-10.html     |
|   Aadinathan  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadinathan-24838.html   |
|    Aadipta    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadipta-20922.html    |
|     Aadir     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadir-11.html       |
|     Aadish    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadish-20945.html     |
|   Aadishree   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadishree-21389.html   |
|     Aadit     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadit-12.html       |
|    Aaditey    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaditey-20921.html    |
|    Aaditeya   |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaditeya-13.html     |
|    Aaditya    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaditya-22619.html    |
|    Aadrika    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadrika-20925.html    |
|     Aadvay    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadvay-22288.html     |
|     Aadvik    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadvik-19508.html     |
|     Aadya     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadya-19557.html     |
|    Aadyasha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aadyasha-20570.html    |
|    Aafreen    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aafreen-19244.html    |
|     Aagam     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aagam-16.html       |
|    Aaghosh    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaghosh-22289.html    |
|     Aagney    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aagney-17.html      |
|    Aagneya    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aagneya-18.html      |
|     Aahan     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahan-19.html       |
|     Aahana    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahana-21194.html     |
|     Aahish    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahish-22290.html     |
|    Aahlaad    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahlaad-21.html      |
|     Aahva     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahva-22.html       |
|     Aahvan    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aahvan-23857.html     |
|     Aakaar    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakaar-23.html      |
|    Aakaash    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakaash-24.html      |
|   Aakanksha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakanksha-19223.html   |
|     Aakar     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakar-25.html       |
|   Aakarshan   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakarshan-26.html     |
|     Aakash    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aakash-19650.html     |
|     Aalap     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aalap-27.html       |
|     Aalok     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aalok-28.html       |
|     Aamil     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aamil-17109.html     |
|     Aamod     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aamod-30.html       |
|     Aanan     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanan-23674.html     |
|     Aanand    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanand-31.html      |
|    Aanandhi   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanandhi-19971.html    |
|  Aanandswarup |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanandswarup-32.html   |
|   Aananthan   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aananthan-26697.html   |
|     Aanav     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanav-19506.html     |
|    Aanchal    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanchal-26403.html    |
|   Aandaleeb   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aandaleeb-33.html     |
|   Aanjaneya   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanjaneya-34.html     |
|     Aanjay    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aanjay-23679.html     |
|      Aapt     |       https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aapt-35.html       |
|   Aaraadhak   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaraadhak-37.html     |
|    Aaradhya   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaradhya-19272.html    |
|    Aaranyan   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaranyan-23680.html    |
|    Aarathi    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarathi-24839.html    |
|     Aarav     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarav-38.html       |
|     Aardik    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aardik-26698.html     |
|    Aarhant    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarhant-39.html      |
|     Aarin     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarin-19496.html     |
|     Aarit     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarit-41.html       |
|     Aariv     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aariv-19507.html     |
|     Aarna     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarna-24840.html     |
|     Aarnav    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarnav-44.html      |
|    Aarodeep   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarodeep-26700.html    |
|     Aaroha    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaroha-21497.html     |
|    Aaromal    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaromal-26701.html    |
|     Aarpit    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarpit-46.html      |
|     Aarsh     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarsh-47.html       |
|    Aarshabh   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarshabh-23864.html    |
|     Aarth     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarth-48.html       |
|     Aarthi    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarthi-24320.html     |
|     Aarti     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarti-24228.html     |
|     Aarul     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarul-19501.html     |
|    Aarunya    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarunya-21502.html    |
|     Aarush    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarush-49.html      |
|    Aarushi    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarushi-50.html      |
|     Aarya     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aarya-19111.html     |
|     Aaryah    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaryah-13617.html     |
|     Aaryan    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaryan-51.html      |
|    Aaryana    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaryana-13618.html    |
|    Aaryanna   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aaryanna-13619.html    |
|   Aashadhar   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashadhar-21503.html   |
|    Aashank    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashank-53.html      |
|     Aashay    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashay-54.html      |
|     Aashi     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashi-24841.html     |
|    Aashirya   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashirya-19779.html    |
|    Aashish    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashish-55.html      |
|    Aashman    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashman-56.html      |
|     Aashna    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashna-19991.html     |
|   Aashutosh   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aashutosh-57.html     |
|     Aastha    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aastha-19567.html     |
|     Aastik    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aastik-60.html      |
|    Aathira    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aathira-24842.html    |
|     Aatish    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aatish-62.html      |
|     Aatmaj    |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aatmaj-63.html      |
|    Aatreya    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aatreya-64.html      |
|     Aayan     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aayan-65.html       |
|      Aayu     |       https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aayu-66.html       |
|     Aayush    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aayush-24843.html     |
|    Aayushi    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aayushi-26998.html    |
|   Aayushmaan  |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aayushmaan-67.html    |
|    Abadhya    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abadhya-19727.html    |
|     Abeesh    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abeesh-19724.html     |
|    Abeesht    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abeesht-20923.html    |
|      Aben     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/aben-19257.html      |
|      Abha     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abha-7340.html      |
|   Abhaiveer   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhaiveer-23649.html   |
|    Abhanja    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhanja-23670.html    |
|     Abhas     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhas-19723.html     |
|     Abhat     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhat-19722.html     |
|     Abhati    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhati-18373.html     |
|     Abhay     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhay-154.html      |
|     Abhaya    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhaya-7341.html     |
|    Abhayan    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhayan-22297.html    |
|  Abhayananda  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhayananda-18027.html  |
|  Abhayaprada  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhayaprada-18028.html  |
|     Abhayd    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhayd-22295.html     |
|     Abhayd    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhayd-22296.html     |
|   Abhaysimha  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhaysimha-23650.html   |
|     Abheek    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abheek-155.html      |
|     Abhey     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhey-22292.html     |
|      Abhi     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhi-156.html       |
|   Abhibhava   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhibhava-18029.html   |
|   Abhicandra  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhicandra-18030.html   |
|    Abhidha    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhidha-18374.html    |
|    Abhidhya   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhidhya-18375.html    |
|     Abhidi    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhidi-18031.html     |
|    Abhigita   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhigita-23855.html    |
|    Abhigna    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhigna-24844.html    |
|   Abhigyaan   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhigyaan-23671.html   |
|    Abhihita   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhihita-18032.html    |
|    Abhijaat   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijaat-157.html     |
|    Abhijat    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijat-18787.html    |
|    Abhijay    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijay-158.html     |
|    Abhijaya   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijaya-18033.html    |
|    Abhijeet   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijeet-17122.html    |
|     Abhiji    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiji-25946.html     |
|    Abhijit    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijit-159.html     |
|    Abhijith   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijith-23839.html    |
|    Abhijun    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijun-160.html     |
|   Abhijvala   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhijvala-18034.html   |
|     Abhik     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhik-161.html      |
|    Abhikama   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhikama-19719.html    |
|   Abhikansh   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhikansh-19720.html   |
|    Abhilasa   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhilasa-18376.html    |
|    Abhilash   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhilash-162.html     |
|   Abhilasha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhilasha-7342.html    |
|     Abhim     |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhim-19721.html     |
|    Abhimand   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhimand-18035.html    |
|    Abhimani   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhimani-18036.html    |
|   Abhimanyu   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhimanyu-163.html    |
| Abhimanyusuta | https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhimanyusuta-18037.html |
|    Abhimoda   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhimoda-18038.html    |
|     Abhin     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhin-164.html      |
|   Abhinabhas  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinabhas-18039.html   |
|    Abhinand   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinand-23672.html    |
|   Abhinanda   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinanda-18040.html   |
|   Abhinandan  |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinandan-165.html    |
|  Abhinandana  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinandana-18788.html  |
|   Abhinatha   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinatha-18041.html   |
|    Abhinav    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinav-166.html     |
|    Abhinava   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinava-18042.html    |
|   Abhinavin   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinavin-19729.html   |
|    Abhinay    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinay-168.html     |
|    Abhinaya   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinaya-23651.html    |
|    Abhineet   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhineet-169.html     |
|    Abhinit    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinit-170.html     |
|   Abhinithi   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinithi-18377.html   |
|   Abhinivesh  |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhinivesh-171.html    |
|   Abhiprithi  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiprithi-18378.html   |
|     Abhir     |      https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhir-172.html      |
|    Abhiraam   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiraam-173.html     |
|    Abhiraj    |     https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiraj-174.html     |
|   Abhiraksh   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiraksh-19733.html   |
|  Abhirakshit  |  https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhirakshit-19732.html  |
|    Abhiram    |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhiram-19728.html    |
|    Abhirami   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhirami-24745.html    |
|    Abhirath   |    https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhirath-175.html     |
|   Abhirathi   |   https://www.prokerala.com/kids/baby-names/abhirathi-18379.html   |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you very much αԋɱҽԃ αмєяιcαη.